# Show $\lim X_k < \infty$ is in tail sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Show $\lim X_k < \infty$ is in tail sigma-algebra

Given random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$, let $\tau = \bigcap_{n\geq1} \sigma(X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, ...)$ be their tail sigma-algebra.

For convenience, $\tau_n \doteq \sigma(X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, ...)$.

What I tried:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$(\lim X_k < \infty) = (\lim X_{k+n} < \infty)$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, (\lim X_k < \infty) = (\lim X_{k+n} < \infty)$

$\to (\lim X_k < \infty) \in \tau_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \because$

$X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, ...$ are RVs on $(\Omega, \tau_n, \mathbb{P})$ --> Is this right?

If so, then obviously $(\lim X_k < \infty) \in \tau$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know whether $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n<\infty$ then you can just pick out some $k\in\mathbb N$ and have a look at sequence $X_{k+1},X_{k+2},\dots$.

The values taken by $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are simply irrelevant when it comes to this question, and this is the case for **any** $k\in\mathbb N$.

This observation allows the conclusion that event $\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n<\infty\}$ belongs to tail $\sigma$-algebra $\tau$.

This reasoning works in many other cases (concerning e.g. $\limsup$, $\liminf$, summation et cetera)

Comment: k instead of n? Thanks but how about my reasoning?

Comment: your reasoning is okay.