# The limiting fraction of tails and the event that 3 consecutive tosses are the same infinitely many times, are both in the tail sigma-field

Tags: probability-theory

Consider tossing a fair coin infinitely. Let $H_n$ be the event that the nth toss turns up heads.

Let $\tau = \bigcap_{n\geq1} \sigma(H_n, H_{n+1}, ...)$.

---

Question 1: Consider the event $A = (\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i \leq 0.25})$, where $r_i$ is a random variable that is equal to 0 if the ith toss is heads and 1 o/w.

How do I prove that $A \in \tau$ ?

What I tried:

$A = (\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i \leq 0.25})$

$= (\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{n+k-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} r_{i + k - 1} \leq 0.25}) \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$\in \sigma(r_k, r_{k+1}, ...)$

$=\sigma(H_{k}, H_{k+1}, ...)$ (*) $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$\to A \in \bigcap_{k \geq 1} \sigma(H_{k}, H_{k+1}, ...) = \tau$

Are those right? In particular I am not sure about (*).

Here is why I think it is right:

$\sigma(r_i) = (\emptyset, H_i, H_i^{C}, \Omega) = \sigma(H_i)$

Is that right?

---

Question 2:

Consider event $B = (\limsup (r_{n} = r_{n+1} = r_{n+2}))$.

How do I prove that $B \in \tau$ ?

What I tried:

$B = (\limsup (r_{n} = r_{n+1} = r_{n+2}))$

$= (\limsup (r_{n+k-1} = r_{n+k} = r_{n+k+1})) \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$\in \sigma(r_k, r_{k+1}, ...)$

$=\sigma(H_{k}, H_{k+1}, ...)$ (*) $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$\to B \in \bigcap_{k \geq 1} \sigma(H_{k}, H_{k+1}, ...) = \tau$

Same concern.

Comment: What is $B=(\limsup r_n=r_{n+1}=r_{n+2})$? I cannot recognize an event in it.

Comment: @drhab "that we infinitely often obtain the same result on three consecutive coin
flips"

Comment: @drhab I guess it is unclear. I will edit it w/ round brackets. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should define $B_n:=\{r_n=r_{n+1}=r_{n+2}\}$ and $B:=\limsup B_n$

Comment: @drhab Right. Thanks. Already edited.

Comment: On question 2 you can put into practice what I told you [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1294129/75923).

Comment: @drhab Thanks. I'm guessing my $\in$ statements are right, then. What about the $\sigma(r_k) = \sigma(H_k)$ stuff?

Comment: That stuff is okay, $r_k$ is measurable w.r.t. some $\sigma$-algebra iff $H_k$ belongs to that $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @drhab Cool intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rk is measurable w.r.t. some σ-algebra iff Hk belongs to that σ-algebra. –  drhab May 24 at 19:27

@drhab Cool intuition. –  BCLC May 28 at 9:10